# Get data from a Promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, tabletop.js

I'm working with [Tabletop.js](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop) to get data from my Google Spreadsheet. In the function, I've invoked a Promise. The only problem is I can't get the data(which is an Array) out of the function.

I have the following code:

```
function getData() {

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    Tabletop.init({key: publicSpreadsheetUrl, callback: showInfo, simpleSheet: true})
    resolve('Done');
  })
}

let arrayWithData = [];

function showInfo (data, tabletop) {
  console.log('showInfo active');
  arrayWithData.push(...data);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(arrayWithData, 'data is here')
    resolve(arrayWithData) // This doesn't work yet
  })
}
 showInfo().then(data => {
   console.log(data, 'data from the Promise')
 }) // This doesn't work
```

I want to use the Array later on in React blocks

**Edit**
With the snippet of Keith, I've got my code working & also added a `reject` handler(inside my Promise of getData() ) from the [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject#Examples).

```
Promise.reject(new Error('fail')).then(function() {
  // not called
}, function(error) {
   console.log(error); // Stacktrace
});
```

The only thing is, that I don't understand the error I get from my `Promise.reject`. It returns the following error:

```
Error: fail
at eval (eval at hmrApply (base.eaab6c8c.js:297), <anonymous>:37:20)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at getData (eval at hmrApply (base.eaab6c8c.js:297), <anonymous>:30:10)
at Object.eval (eval at hmrApply (base.eaab6c8c.js:297), <anonymous>:63:1)
at newRequire (script.726c79f3.js:48)
at hmrAccept (base.eaab6c8c.js:328)
at base.eaab6c8c.js:214
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at WebSocket.ws.onmessage (base.eaab6c8c.js:212)
```

Comment: Why do you create Promises that resolve immediately? What are you *actually* trying to do here? You're also not passing anything in your `showInfo()` call, although the functions seems to expect `data, tabletop`

Comment: With the Promise I'm trying to pass data (which is arrayWithData) so I can use it somewhere else, like in other functions

Comment: You don't need a Promise for that, at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a couple of issues here..

Firstly, you have `showInfo().then`, I'm pretty sure you meant to do -> `getData().then(`

Your next problem is your getData function,.  like @ChrisG said your just resolving a promise instantly here, below is more likely what you meant to do.

```
function getData() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    Tabletop.init({key: publicSpreadsheetUrl, 
      callback: function (data, tabletop) { resolve(showInfo(data, tabletop)); },
      simpleSheet: true})
  })
}
```

Lastly your showInfo is not doing anything `async` so it can be simplified to ->

```
function showInfo (data, tabletop) {
  console.log('showInfo active');
  arrayWithData.push(...data);
  console.log(arrayWithData, 'data is here')
  return arrayWithData;
}
```

One last thing, there is no error checking here, normally callbacks have some way to inform you of an error condition, then you could also add the `reject` handler.

Comment: I've updated my code with a reject handler and it returns an error see the main post.

Comment: You might have to skip the error checking, as a quick look at tabletop, there is none.  eg. the source does -> `} catch (e) { console.error(e);  }`  That not great :(, you might want to contact author and ask to implement error handling.